# Deleting and updating an item from the database

Tags: database, vb.net

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LoginSystemDataSet.Administrator' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.AdministratorTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginSystemDataSet.Administrator)

    With lstDetails.Columns
        .Add("Username", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        .Add("Password", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        .Add("Email", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    End With
End Sub 

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    If lstDetails.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        Dim Button = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this Data?", _
        "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        If Button = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

            Dim dt As New LoginSystemDataSet.AdministratorDataTable
            Dim ds As New LoginSystemDataSetTableAdapters.AdministratorTableAdapter

            AdministratorBindingSource.List.Remove(lstDetails.SelectedItems.Item(0))

            AdministratorTableAdapter.Update(LoginSystemDataSet.Administrator)
            lstDetails.Items.Remove(lstDetails.SelectedItems.Item(0))

            'Dim da As New DataTable

            'AdministratorTableAdapter.DeleteQuery(lstDetails.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text)
            'lstDetails.Items.Remove(lstDetails.SelectedItems.Item(0))

            '   AdministratorTableAdapter.Update(da)
        End If
    Else
        AdministratorBindingSource.CancelEdit()
        MsgBox("No items is selected in the list provided", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AdministratorBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.AdministratorBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LoginSystemDataSet)
End Sub
```

I'm trying to remove a row by clicking an item in the listview, then delete it from the selected row in the database. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `Row.Delete`, rather than just removing a row from parent. The difference is described here:

- [DataRow Deletion (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03c7a3zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)